# What action should be taken on late answers that just rephrase another answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I've seen this plenty of times on late or first answers where the person answering the question has either not bother to read the other answers or has blatently copied an accepted answer and just rephrased it.

These answers add nothing to the question and simply pollute it and dilute useful content, what action should be taken?

Comment: down vote as that signals *not useful*.

Comment: Is a downvote sufficient?

Comment: well, anything else will probably fail, either because reviewers will not spot what is wrong with it and moderators will not delete anything that resembles something that might have value.

Comment: And yes, down votes are sufficient, specially if everybody uses them, also on answers. That should help bring such lazy posters closer to an answer ban.

Comment: Okay, cheers! That answers my question

Comment: Besides down-voting, you may also leave a comment stating that the answer does not add anything new to the existing answers. Best case, the user deletes the answer on their own.

Comment: Or up vote ... if the rephrasing results in an answer that is good enough to be upvoted in its own right, especially so if it results in an answer that is better than the original.  Some first answers are written in an awful hurry by the rep-thirsty and really aren't terribly well written.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Simply leave a polite comment "Hmm, that answer seems identical to answer _ _ _ above."  As others have said, note that very often, indeed, the best answers come from slight refinement of existing answers; so don't confuse what you're talking about (some passing idiot pointlessly copies and pastes an answer, because they think they'll win a tshirt or something) with the *normal process* of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Downvote** if you feel like the new answer doesn't add anything beyond the existing answers. Also **leave a comment** referencing the near-identical existing answer to make the reason for the downvote obvious to the poster as well as others viewing the answer in isolation (who may otherwise decide to upvote the seemingly good answer, especially if they see a seemingly undeserved downvote).

It's worth noting that some answers are not well phrased in the first place, or some may have trouble understanding them for whatever reason, so a rephrasing could be a welcome addition.

Under some circumstances an edit to the existing answer might seem like the more appropriate action to take (when the edit would be unambiguously better rather than just different), but those are presumably the exception rather than the rule and you'll need to decide on your own whether downvoting is justified.

---

If it's an *exact* (word-for-word) copy of an older answer, one might consider flagging that with a custom reason referencing the other answer. Although a moderator will need to confirm whether that's an appropriate action to take.

The usefulness of rephrasings are often very much subjective, so I would *not* suggest using flagging for that, but rather only for exact duplicates of old answers, which is undeniably unwanted content.